# Изменять класс в div при изменении размеров экрана

Tags: javascript

Доброго всем вечера господа

```
//js
var scrollWidth = document.documentElement.scrollWidth;
var realW = scrollWidth;
```

имеем переменные, о реальном размере окна, которое смотрит пользователь. Ест-но можно изменить размер экрана (сделать не на весь экран, а на часть). Допустим есть ширина в 1000px и пользователь елозит браузер по ширине, то шире то уже..

Можно как то автоматом менять класс у div'ов в стиле 'туда-обратно', при изменении реальной ширины окна браузера?

```
//html
<div id="a1" class="a1">
    <div id="a11" class="a11">
    11
    </div>
    <div id="a12" class="a12">
    12
    </div>
    <div id="a13" class="a13">
    13
        <div id="a131" class="a131">
        131
        </div>
        <div id="a132" class="a132">
        132
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

К примеру если загружаем страницу, сразу проверяем, если realW>1000 - стиль один, если меньше - стили другие, но при изменении окна - идет пересчет и изменение автоматом, т.е. в моем случае  замена указанных классов

```
если ширина уменьшается стала меньше 1000, меняем классы у
id1 -> class="a1s"
id11 -> class="a11s"
id12 -> class="a12s"
id13 -> class="a13s"
id131 -> class="a131s"
id132 -> class="a132s"

если ширина уменьшается стала больше 1000, меняем классы на те, что были изначально
id1 -> class="a1"
id11 -> class="a11"
id12 -> class="a12"
id13 -> class="a13"
id131 -> class="a131"
id132 -> class="a132"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в случае с jQuery стоит смотреть в сторону event resize():

```
$(window).resize(function () { /* сюда функционал */ });
```

который срабатыват в момент смены пользователем размера окна,
далее:

```
var width = $('body').innerWidth()
```

даст вам текущий размер, сравните его с тем критерием, который вы указали
и примените нужный класс, предварительно убрав те которые у него уже есть:

```
if (width < 1000) {
    $('.a1').removeClass('a1').addClass('a1s');
    ... // остальные классы
}
```

Документация:

- [resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)
- [innerWidtgh()](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/)
- [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)
- [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Comment: Огх.. вот так бы документация по JQ писалась! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вариант **без** использования jQuery.

```
window.onresize = function () {
    document.getElementById ("id").className = "new_class_name";
};
```